# Dynamic save to csv using arrays

Tags: python, arrays, csv, dynamic, iteration

I'm using the csv module to save arrays to csv, however I want to make it abit more dynamic. Apologies if this is already up here, I tried searching but to no avail.
this is my current code, it works well....

```
filename = 'zeroTime_.csv'        #save to csv
f = open(filename, "w")
f.write("{},{},{},{}\n".format("R[0]", "F[0]","R[1]", "F[1]"))
for x in zip(R[0], F[0],R[1], F[1]):
    f.write("{},{},{},{}\n".format(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]))
f.close()
```

However I want to make it so that if array R has more than 2 columns in, it will still work
I tried creating the `"R[0]", "F[0]","R[1]", "F[1]"` as a string and just using that but it doesnt like it, my code creates a `R` and `F` for each channel denoted by `NumCh`:

```
for x in range(NumCh):
    title = title +'"R['+str(x)+']",'+'"F['+str(x)+']",'
    bracket = bracket + '{},{},'
title = title[:-1]
bracket = bracket[:-1]
bracket = bracket + '\n"'

filename = 'zeroTime_.csv'        #save to csv
f = open(filename, "w")
f.write(bracket.format(title))
for x in zip(R[0], F[0],R[1], F[1]):
    f.write(bracket.format(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]))
f.close()
```

Gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "base.py", line 8, in <module>
    b = pd.proc(NumCh, a)
  File "C:\Users\jtpkalaverick\Documents\Python\module\time_proc.py", line 24, in proc
    f.write(bracket.format(title))
IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
```

(I'm running this within a module addressed as `pd`.)

edit (30.06.22)

i have 2 modules tick_proc that produces some arbitrary arrays and time_proc that does some basic maths on the arrays. NumCh and samples are passed into the modules and are just ints

main code:

```
import tick_proc as tp
import time_proc as pd
NumCh = 2
samples = 10

a = tp.collect_data(NumCh, samples)
b = pd.proc(NumCh, a)
print('b', b)
```

tick proc:

```
print('Importing module "TickProc"')
R = []
F = []
def collect_data(NumCh, samples):
    for x in range(NumCh):
        R.append([])
        F.append([])

    for x in range(NumCh):
        for y in range(samples):
            R[x].append(y*x)
            F[x].append(y*x -1)

    return F, R
```

time_proc:

```
import csv
def proc(NumCh, a):
    R = a[0]
    F = a[1]
    T = []
    bracket = '"'
    title = ''
    vars = ''

    for x in range(NumCh):
        T.append([])
        title = title +'"R['+str(x)+']",'+'"F['+str(x)+']",'
        bracket = bracket + '{},{},'
    title = title[:-1]
    bracket = bracket[:-1]
    bracket = bracket + '\n"'
    print(bracket)
    print(title)
    for i in range(NumCh):
        for j in range(len(R[i])):
            T[i].append(R[i][j]-F[i][j])

    filename = 'zeroTime_.csv'        #save to csv
    f = open(filename, "w")
    f.write(bracket.format(title))
    for x in zip(R[0], F[0],R[1], F[1]):
        f.write(bracket.format(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]))
    f.close()
    return T
```

Comment: Where are you using the `csv` module?

Comment: could you also show an example of `NumCh` ?

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your comments, I've edited the post to include more of the code. NumCh is brought in from the main code and csv is loaded in the module that its called from. Many thanks